# Linq to DataSet query isn't returning expected EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>

Tags: linq, datatable, dataview

dtbl isn't a strongly typed DataTable, but all these nonetheless work fine (so namespaces and references appear to be ok)

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> a = dtbl.AsEnumerable();
DataView                         b = dtbl.AsDataView();
IEnumerable<DataRow>             c = from y in dtbl.AsEnumerable() select y;
```

however, both these yield:
"Cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable to EnumerableRowCollection"

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> d = from y in dtbl.AsEnumerable() select y;
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> e = dtbl.AsEnumerable().Select(y=>y);
```

the error makes sense, but queries returning EnumerableRowCollection are shown in
MSDN example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669080(v=vs.110).aspx and here on
stackoverflow without apparent hiccup

this is a showstopper, so a solution would be very welcome, as I need to get to:

```
DataView view = (query performing filter and sort on dtbl).AsDataView();
```

Comment: This `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> d = from y in dtbl.AsEnumerable() select y;` or `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> d2 = dtbl.AsEnumerable();` work fine. Not really sure how you are getting the exception, try clean-rebuild, restart visual studio

Comment: Thank you @Habib, already tried rebuild, restart, and shutdown- recycle. Your being able to do it means I must have something local here. I'm running VS13 update 3 and building .net 4.5.

Comment: What does the intellisense on `Select()` say?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this with VS 2012 and .Net 4.5, but a work-around could be to bypass the syntactic sugar of extension methods and use the `Select` method directly off the static class in which it is defined:

```
EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Select(dtbl.AsEnumerable(), d => d)
```

See [EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.enumerablerowcollectionextensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I added the EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions version to the pass-throughs and it worked. Many thanks!! (and my UPVOTE from here, as I've not yet reputation to do it for real)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: it was an interfering extension method; I defined a list of "pass-though" extensions (Select, OrderBy, etc) to allow functions in other source files to avoid "using System.Linq", as well as allowing all Linq calls to be quickly found by reference.

Turns out there are undocumented (and apparently inaccessible) versions of the extension methods like EnumerableRowCollection.Select<>() that get hidden by the pass-throughs, and that are defined in an extension class that so far I can't find.

Anyway, I can get there from here by either finding the extension class, or yanking the pass-throughs.